# URL from Firebase Dynamic Links generates a "Suspicious Link" warning

Tags: firebase, gmail, firebase-dynamic-links

So, I have a web application where users can register and when they do, a confirmation email is sent to their inbox to confirm their email. This email that is sent contains a link that takes you to the log in page, and we use firebase to convert that link into a short dynamic link, example: https://xm5z5.app.goo.gl/wiRt.

However, when this link is clicked, the user gets a "suspicious link" warning from google and I can't seem to understand why this happens. I've read that a few other people with web apps have the same issue with google flagging one of their links as suspicious. Why could this be and how can this be solved?

Comment: I'm facing the issue with page.link , did you find the solution ?